# adding a space after each character in multiple li

Tags: jquery, for-loop, append, slice

I have a bunch of words in li tags, but I would like to add a space after each character in each. I thought this would work, but I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help me out?

```
$("#words li").each( function(){

var val = $(this).html();
var len = val.length

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
$(this).html().slice(i, i+1).append("<br>");    
};

});
```

Comment: I beleive it should have been `$(this).text().length;` instead of `val.length`

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to deal val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to add a line break

```
$("#words li").html( function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/(.)/g, '$1<br/>')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D8aFw/)

Try this if you want to add a space

```
$("#words li").html( function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/(.)/g, '$1 ')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D8aFw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way : ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HMB98/))

```
$("#words li").each( function(){    
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("").join("<br/>"));    
});
```

Or: ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HMB98/1/))

```
$("#words li").each(function () {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.split("").join("<br/>");
});
```